# Python argparse: Make at least one argument required

Tags: python, argparse

I've been using `argparse` for a Python program that can `-process`, `-upload` or both:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Log archiver arguments.')
parser.add_argument('-process', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-upload',  action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The program is meaningless without at least one parameter. How can I configure `argparse` to force at least one parameter to be chosen?

**UPDATE:**

Following the comments: What's the Pythonic way to parametrize a program with at least one option?

Comment: `-x` is universally a flag and optional. Cut the `-` if it's required.

Comment: Couldn't you make `process` the default behavior (without the need to specify any options) and allow the user to change that into `upload` if *that* option is set? Usually, options should be optional, hence the name. Required options should be avoided (this is also in the `argparse`  docs).

Comment: @AdamMatan It is almost three years since you have asked your question but I liked the challenge hidden in it and used the advantage of new solutions being available for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

```
if not (args.process or args.upload):
    parser.error('No action requested, add -process or -upload')
```

Comment: That's probably the only way, if `argparse` has no built-in option for this.

Comment: note: this check has to come after `parser.parse_args()`

Answer (score 48):

I know this is old as dirt, but the way to require one option but forbid more than one (XOR) is like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-process', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-upload',  action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Output:

```
>opt.py  
usage: multiplot.py [-h] (-process | -upload)  
multiplot.py: error: one of the arguments -process -upload is required  
    
>opt.py -upload  
Namespace(process=False, upload=True)  
  
>opt.py -process  
Namespace(process=True, upload=False)  
  
>opt.py -upload -process  
usage: multiplot.py [-h] (-process | -upload)  
multiplot.py: error: argument -process: not allowed with argument -upload
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP doesn't want an XOR. It's either or both, but not none so your last test case doesn't meet their requirements.

Comment: @kdopen: the respondent did clarify that this is a variation on the original question, which I found to be useful: "the way to require one option but forbid more than one " Perhaps the etiquette of Stack Exchange would call for a new question instead.  But having this answer present here helped me...

Comment: I will second the usefulness of this answer, this ended up being exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the initial question

Comment: How does this answer the question of "at least one"?

Answer (score 46):

```
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
if not any(args.values()):
    parser.error('No arguments provided.')
```

Answer (score 21):

If not the 'or both' part (I have initially missed this) you could use something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Log archiver arguments.')
parser.add_argument('--process', action='store_const', const='process', dest='mode')
parser.add_argument('--upload',  action='store_const', const='upload', dest='mode')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.mode:
    parser.error("One of --process or --upload must be given")
```

Though, probably it would be a better idea to use [subcommands](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) instead.

Comment: I think he wants to allow `--process` OR `--upload`, not XOR. This prevents both options from being set at the same time.

Answer (score 11):

## Requirements Review

- use `argparse` (I will ignore this one)
- allow one or two actions to be called (at least one required).
- try to by Pythonic (I would rather call it "POSIX"-like)

There are also some implicit requirements when living on command line:

- explain the usage to the user in a way which is easy to understand
- options shall be optional
- allow specifying flags and options
- allow combining with other parameters (like file name or names).

## Sample solution using `docopt` (file `managelog.py`):

```
"""Manage logfiles
Usage:
    managelog.py [options] process -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py [options] upload -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py [options] process upload -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py -h

Options:
    -V, --verbose      Be verbose
    -U, --user <user>  Username
    -P, --pswd <pswd>  Password

Manage log file by processing and/or uploading it.
If upload requires authentication, you shall specify <user> and <password>
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
```

Try to run it:

```
$ python managelog.py
Usage:
    managelog.py [options] process -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py [options] upload -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py [options] process upload -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py -h
```

Show the help:

```
$ python managelog.py -h
Manage logfiles
Usage:
    managelog.py [options] process -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py [options] upload -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py [options] process upload -- <logfile>...
    managelog.py -h

Options:
    -V, --verbose      Be verbose
    -U, --user <user>  Username
    -P, --pswd <pswd>  P    managelog.py [options] upload -- <logfile>...

Manage log file by processing and/or uploading it.
If upload requires authentication, you shall specify <user> and <password>
```

And use it:

```
$ python managelog.py -V -U user -P secret upload -- alfa.log beta.log
{'--': True,
 '--pswd': 'secret',
 '--user': 'user',
 '--verbose': True,
 '-h': False,
 '<logfile>': ['alfa.log', 'beta.log'],
 'process': False,
 'upload': True}
```

## Short alternative `short.py`

There can be even shorter variant:

```
"""Manage logfiles
Usage:
    short.py [options] (process|upload)... -- <logfile>...
    short.py -h

Options:
    -V, --verbose      Be verbose
    -U, --user <user>  Username
    -P, --pswd <pswd>  Password

Manage log file by processing and/or uploading it.
If upload requires authentication, you shall specify <user> and <password>
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
```

Usage looks like this:

```
$ python short.py -V process upload  -- alfa.log beta.log
{'--': True,
 '--pswd': None,
 '--user': None,
 '--verbose': True,
 '-h': False,
 '<logfile>': ['alfa.log', 'beta.log'],
 'process': 1,
 'upload': 1}
```

Note, that instead of boolean values for "process" and "upload" keys there are counters.

It turns out, we cannot prevent duplication of these words:

```
$ python short.py -V process process upload  -- alfa.log beta.log
{'--': True,
 '--pswd': None,
 '--user': None,
 '--verbose': True,
 '-h': False,
 '<logfile>': ['alfa.log', 'beta.log'],
 'process': 2,
 'upload': 1}
```

## Conclusions

Designing good command line interface can be challenging sometime.

There are multiple aspects of command line based program:

- good design of command line
- selecting/using proper parser

`argparse` offers a lot, but restricts possible scenarios and can become very complex.

With `docopt` things go much shorter while preserving readability and offering high degree of flexibility. If you manage getting parsed arguments from dictionary and do some of conversions (to integer, opening files..) manually (or by other library called [`schema`](https://github.com/halst/schema)), you may find `docopt` good fit for command line parsing.

Answer (score 7):

For http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 I am exploring ways of generalizing the `mutually_exclusive_group` concept to handle cases like this.

With this development `argparse.py`, https://github.com/hpaulj/argparse_issues/blob/nested/argparse.py 
I am able to write:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', 
    description='Log archiver arguments.')
group = parser.add_usage_group(kind='any', required=True,
    title='possible actions (at least one is required)')
group.add_argument('-p', '--process', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-u', '--upload',  action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

which produces the following `help`:

```
usage: PROG [-h] (-p | -u)

Log archiver arguments.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit

possible actions (at least one is required):
  -p, --process
  -u, --upload
```

This accepts inputs like '-u',  '-up', '--proc --up' etc.

It ends up running a test similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723066/901925, though the error message needs to be clearer:

```
usage: PROG [-h] (-p | -u)
PROG: error: some of the arguments process upload is required
```

I wonder:

- are the parameters `kind='any', required=True` clear enough (accept any of the group; at least one is required)?
- is usage `(-p | -u)` clear?  A required mutually_exclusive_group produces the same thing.  Is there some alternative notation?
- is using a group like this more intuitive than `phihag's` simple test?

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is by using python inbuilt module **add_mutually_exclusive_group**.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Log archiver arguments.')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-process', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-upload',  action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

If you want only one argument to be selected by command line just use required=True as an argument for group

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
```

Comment: How does this get you "at least one" - doesn't it get you "exactly one"?

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP doesn't want an XOR. OP's looking for OR

Answer (score 5):

If you require a python program to run with at least one parameter, add an argument that **doesn't** have the option prefix  (- or -- by default) and set `nargs=+` (Minimum of one argument required). The problem with this method I found is that if you do not specify the argument, argparse will generate a "too few arguments" error and not print out the help menu. If you don't need that functionality, here's how to do it in code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Your program description')
parser.add_argument('command', nargs="+", help='describe what a command is')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I **think** that when you add an argument with the option prefixes, nargs governs the entire argument parser and not just the option. (What I mean is, if you have an `--option` flag with `nargs="+"`, then `--option` flag expects at least one argument. If you have `option` with `nargs="+"`, it expects at least one argument overall.)

Comment: You could add `choices=['process','upload']` to that argument.

Answer (score 5):

This achieves the purpose and this will also be reflected in the argparse autogenerated `--help` output, which is IMHO what most sane programmers want (also works with optional arguments):

```
parser.add_argument(
    'commands',
    nargs='+',                      # require at least 1
    choices=['process', 'upload'],  # restrict the choice
    help='commands to execute'
)
```

Official documentation on this:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use sub-parsers?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Log archiver arguments.')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name', help='sub-command help')
parser_process = subparsers.add_parser('process', help='Process logs')
parser_upload = subparsers.add_parser('upload', help='Upload logs')
args = parser.parse_args()

print("Subparser: ", args.subparser_name)
```

Now `--help` shows:

```
$ python /tmp/aaa.py --help
usage: aaa.py [-h] {process,upload} ...

Log archiver arguments.

positional arguments:
  {process,upload}  sub-command help
    process         Process logs
    upload          Upload logs

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
$ python /tmp/aaa.py
usage: aaa.py [-h] {process,upload} ...
aaa.py: error: too few arguments
$ python3 /tmp/aaa.py upload
Subparser:  upload
```

You can add additional options to these sub-parsers as well. Also instead of using that `dest='subparser_name'` you can also bind functions to be directly called on given sub-command (see docs).

Answer (score 2):

For cases like

```
parser.add_argument("--a")
parser.add_argument("--b")
```

We can use the following

```
if not args.a and not args.b:
    parser.error("One of --a or --b must be present")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use append_const to a list of actions and then check that the list is populated:

```
parser.add_argument('-process', dest=actions, const="process", action='append_const')
parser.add_argument('-upload',  dest=actions, const="upload", action='append_const')

args = parser.parse_args()

if(args.actions == None):
    parser.error('Error: No actions requested')
```

You can even specify the methods directly within the constants.

```
def upload:
    ...

parser.add_argument('-upload',  dest=actions, const=upload, action='append_const')
args = parser.parse_args()

if(args.actions == None):
    parser.error('Error: No actions requested')

else:
    for action in args.actions:
        action()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Log archiver arguments.')
    parser.add_argument('-process', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-upload',  action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Maybe try:

```
    if len([False for arg in vars(args) if vars(args)[arg]]) == 0: 
        parsers.print_help()
        exit(-1)
```

At least this is what I just used; hopefully this helps someone in the future!