# python3 argparse: checking combination of boolean arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a set of boolean argparse options: `--foo/--no-foo`, `--bar/--no-bar`, `--baz/--no-baz`

My script makes sense only if at least one of those options is set to `True`.

I'd like to issue an Exception correctly processed by `argparse`, which will be managed as a command line error clear message.

But `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` is not a good option because it required the option as first argument to the constructor ... and my case is related to multiple options.

[Edit based on @00 comment:] The only solution I've got now is to raise, at the end of the command line processing, a ValueError is none of those options are set. But it is an exception, which is not user friendly.

What is the way to proceed in such cases?

Thanks a lot.

P.S.: Code to generate those options:

```py
    @classmethod
    def addBoolean(
        cls, argumentParser, dest, helpTrue, helpFalse,
        default=None
    ):
        """Adds a boolean option
        - argumentParser: A argparse.ArgumentHelper object
        - dest: The destination argument
        - helpTrue: The documentation of the True option
        - helpFalse: The documentation of the False option
        - default: Value to use if not required and not provided

        When no default (None) is provided, required is True

        The option will be --{dest} and --no-{dest}
        """
        # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments

        required = (default is None)
        group = argumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(
            required=required,
        )
        group.add_argument(
            f'--{dest}',
            dest=dest,
            action='store_true',
            help=helpTrue
        )
        group.add_argument(
            f'--no-{dest}',
            dest=dest,
            action='store_false',
            help=helpFalse
        )
        if not required:
            argumentParser.set_defaults(**{dest: default})
```

Comment: You could always throw an exception/error message after the initial parsing, that is, code the check yourself outside of argparse. Perhaps less nice, but I'd say that it would work fine.

Comment: @00 Indeed, and that's what I do now. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723066/6018688 which uses `parser.error` after a custom check past parsing.

Comment: Thanks @fabianegli. I have not seen this.

Comment: @MichaelHooreman You are most welcome. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: @fabianegli Perfectly ;-)

Comment: An alternative to the good answers above: you can also set one of the arguments to default true if the others are false. This is how we handle some of our arguments and works well for first-time users who don't necessarily know which methods to use. This might not be applicable in your use case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Python argparse: Make at least one argument required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722936):

Flexible `argparse` errors can be created using `parser.error("error message")`

(see comments of @fabianegli in the question)